# Unparseable date: "2018-07-03T01:00:21.000+0000" Cannot parse this format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Try 1:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+/-HHmm");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = format.parse(createdDate2);
```

Try 2:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = format.parse(createdDate2);
```

Try 3:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = format.parse(createdDate2);
```

Nothing seems to work with this format:

Any help?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using the `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date` classes? Those are all long outdated, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: guess, why Oracle has not deprecated  Date object completely? because there is still lots of code using Date Objects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date date = format.parse(createdDate2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not exactly be what you want, but if the timezone offset would be written with a colon separator e.g. `+00:00` it's the `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`

```
OffsetDateTime d = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-07-03T01:00:21.000+00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(d); // 2018-07-03T01:00:21Z
```

Comment: Good suggestion. To parse `+0000` as an offset, you may build a `DatetimeFormatter` using a format pattern string with `xx` for offset.

Comment: When I try to parse this String as CharacterSequence : '2018-07-10T01:00:03.000+0000' 

I get this error: `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-07-10T01:00:03.000+0000' could not be parsed at index 23`

Comment: @NagendraSingh That's because there is no colon in the timezone offset.